# Script return multiple values

Tags: powershell

We have a powershell script that download data from an url, verify the data using some generic and simple rules and return success or failed (0 or 1). Here is an example

```
Get-data -uri "http://www.google.com/some_path"
```

This script is used successfully in many situations. However, in some cases the simple rules implemented in the Get-data script is not enough to verify the data. We do not want to add a lot of domain specific rules into the Get-data. It would be much better if the parent script performed the additional verification but then it needs access to the raw data. How can we return both a boolean return value of success \ failed and a data object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about returning an object instead of a bool:

```
$props = @{
  Success = $result
  Data = $theData
}
$object = new-object psobject -Property $props
return $object
```

You can get the object like so:

```
$result = Get-data -uri "http://www.google.com/some_path"
if($result.success) {
    # Do all the stuff you want with $result.data
}
```

Read more about creating objects [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7804.powershell-creating-custom-objects.aspx).